# Caches Dissapear from elasticache (memcached)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, memcached

I set something to memcached with

```
$M->set('thingtobeset', $resultsforcache, 60*60*24*7*6);
```

It should keep there for 42 days, unfortunately it seems to be unset in under 10 minutes.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memcache FAQ on [Expiration](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgramming#Expiration)

> Expiration times can be set from 0, meaning "never expire", to 30
>   days. Any time higher than 30 days is interpreted as a unix timestamp
>   date. If you want to expire an object on january 1st of next year,
>   this is how you do that.